# Regex match string part on specific lines

Tags: regex, string

I need to run advanced find and replace using regex. I have a CSV similar to the following:

```
"Item 1a,,,,
,,Item 1b,,,,
,,Item 1c"
"Item 2a,,,,
,,Item 2b,,,,"
```

I need to remove the trailing commas for lines that start with a " quote.
I can match the correct lines like so:

```
(".*?),,,,$
```

The problem is, that selects the entire row, rather than just the trailing commas.

Anybody know how to match this correctly? so that only the commas are matched, on lines that start with " quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already capturing the content before the commas, just put it all back using a back reference in the replace:

```
Search: ^(".*?),+$
Replace: $1
```

Note: You need to anchor you regex to start of line `^` to match a quote there (otherwise it will match a quote anywhere in the line).

Comment: @hwnd but he doesn't want to highlight, he wants to replace the commas with blank to remove them. From OP's question: *I need to run advanced find and replace using regex ... to remove the trailing commas for lines that start with a "*. OP *thinks* he has to match only the commas, but this is a solution that works.

Comment: I get that, it is replacing (only selecting the commas): https://regex101.com/r/aQ4sI6/2 `Bohemian is correct, it's too easy to just backreference the captured group in the replacement.`